# boost::serialize and std::chrono::system_clock::time_point

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, c++11

I am trying to serialize a class that contains a std::chrono::system_clock::time_point with boost::serialize.

```
template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned int version) {
    ar & timePoint_;
}
```

However I get the error:

Error   1   error C2039: 'serialize' : is not a member of 'std::chrono::time_point<_Clock>' c:\boost_1_54_0\boost\serialization\access.hpp  118

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Use

> `boost::serialization::make_binary_object(void * t, size_t size);`

from 
`boost/serialization/binary_object.hpp` wchich can be used like this:

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp;
ar & boost::serialization::make_binary_object(&tp, sizeof(tp));
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work using the following intrusive function (in the class which has the timepoint_ as a member function)

```
template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned int version) {
    char * ptr = reinterpret_cast<char *>(&timePoint_);
    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof(timePoint_); ++i)
        ar & ptr[i];
    /*snip*/
}
```